Можно ли сонет 130 Шекспира считать пародией?
И черной проволокой вьется прядь... Сонет 130
Кстати, ударение смещено? ПроволОкой? Ведь такое ударение соответствует размеру стиха. А проволОка, может, и не прОволока совсем?
Но была ли проволока во времена Шекспира? Дело, конечно, не в проволоке, а в самом сонете. Мне было любопытно, что же это за проволока того времени, да еще в качестве сравнения. В Сети есть информация по теме — оказывается, интересно было не только мне: "Терзают смутные сомнения, что во времена Шекспира была проволока".
А это уже подробнее:
О «проволоке» нужно сказать особо – это самая 
распространенная погрешность в переводах 130-го 
сонета. В оригинале: «If hairs be wires, black 
wires grow on her head.» Как видите, дело не в том, 
что «проволока», а в том, что «черная», а не 
золотая. Золотая проволока, а точнее нить для шитья 
– популярная во времена Шекспира метафора. Выходит, 
что она, увы, – не златовласка (времена меняются, 
но блондинки не теряют своего статуса эталона 
красоты). Если взять начало сонета Бартоломью 
Гриффина опубликованного незадолго до публикации 
130-го, то видна причина иронии Шекспира:

Но более всего любопытна эта статья
Там сказано, что сонет является пародией, причем это известно  давно. (Впервые это мнение было высказано Н. Стороженко в 1902 году.)
Сонет 130 пародиен как по форме, так и по содержанию? Но разве кто-то из известных литературоведов так считает? Утверждение не выглядит убедительным...
  Пародийность его формы заключается в 
 "перевернутости"  композиции. В классических 
любовных сонетах Петраркой в открытых комплиментах 
воспевалась красота возлюбленной с целью "уложить" 
её в постель. А в сонете Шекспира героиня уже 
выступает в роли любовницы - она "mistress" 
(любовница). Этим словом он определяет героиню уже 
"во первЫх строках" своей работы. И только к концу 
стихотворения она превращается в "my love" - 
любимую.

Далее подробно разбираются все метафоры, которые обычно считаются средствами художественной выразительности. Статья авторская и весьма сомнительная, но вопросы любопытные:
 В средневековой Европе среди представителей высших 
 сословий загар считался признаком низкого 
 происхождения, уделом людей, вынужденных работать 
 на открытом воздухе. Аристократическая бледность 
 считалась признаком богатства. Модницы ради 
 красоты шли на самые настоящие жертвы - чтобы 
 заполучить вожделенную бледность, девушки делали 
 себе кровопускание, прятались от солнца. Кожу 
 специально отбеливали.

 Красивые волосы в понимании англичан той эпохи 
 должны были быть светлыми и мягкими, как бы 
 струящимися. А здесь они не просто тёмные, а 
 черные. И что ещё более ужасно - напоминают 
 проволоку, настолько они жёсткие. Шекспир дважды 
 прибегает к метафоре "проволока" - "be wires", 
 "black wires".

И т.д.
СМИ: "Восхищался белизной кожи" — в пьесах Шекспира нашли признаки расизма? Писатель в своих произведениях систематически противопоставлял «тёмное» «светлому», отдавая предпочтение последнему.
ВОПРОС: Можно ли считать сонет 130  пародией или все это фантазии?  Более всего меня интересует ЯЗЫКОВОЙ анализ текста (лексика и метафоры времен Шекспира).

Вообще, кроме слова dun, который может быть цветом помоев, все остальные слова не такие уж неупотребимые, даже "проволока", вполне употребима, но возможно не была классической формой сравнения в то время. А <<wir "metal drawn out into a fine thread,">> - это наша Златовласка, потому что это именно сложно выделанный, металлический(драгоценный), скрученный <<Old Norse viravirka "filigree work," Swedish vira "to twist," Old High German wiara "fine gold work">> материал для создания ювелирных украшений, но не являющийся украшением ещё. В этом ирония, что Шекспир идёт не в слово золото, а в слово проволока>золото или "до" золото. То есть указывает на причинные моменты. А не на моменты штампов классических сравнений которые пошли от Петрарки:

Лирика Петрарки всегда наполнена изяществом, стремлением к красоте,
она очень артистична. Так, в изображении Лауры он пользуется
вычурными, необычными сравнениями: ее волосы — золото, лицо — теплый
снег, брови — эбеновое дерево, зубы — жемчуг, уста — лепестки роз.

И тут была тонкая игра слов, как мне кажется, то есть Шекспир шёл по краешку комплимент-оскорбление, ну или хотел сделать стих таковым в основе, выйдя за пределы штампов. Поэтому это не пародия, пародия - это штамп, Шекспир же пытается найти новые способы для передачи того, что считает красивым и поэтичным.
Насчёт "тело пахнет телом" - тут уже Маршак, как мне кажется, не улавливает иронии и скатывается в грубость.
Than in the breath that from my mistress reeks
Breath - это выдыхаемый воздух, дыхание, дыхание связано с душой и духом, то есть если что-то живое, оно дышит, reek - испарение и дым. Оба этих слова могут иметь такое значение как вонь. Но что такое вонь? Вонь - это просто резкий характерный запах, вонь может обозначать запахи, которые считаются, именно считаются, приятными. Но даже наше слово благо+вонье - так же содержит корень вонь. То есть вонь - это просто резкий запах, а семантика "приятный" содержится в слове благо. Но Зловонье - это совсем другое слово. Также дыхание-душа-дух - это не про тело. Поэтому я тут не соглашусь с Маршаком, который конечно создал образ, но этот образ, несмотря на яркость, не отражает иронии Шекспира. Как не отражает и концовка совсем. И пятистопный ямб стиха в 10 слогов у Маршака нарушен и имеет лишний безударный слог, но это уже мелочи.
Поэтому да, Шекспир действует смело и провоцирует, но не на грубость, а на столкновение штампового восприятия блага и света, и живой красоты. В этом мне видится смысл сонета.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
